# Is there a way to clear a flowlayoutpanel? C# Windows form

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

Im creating a timetable application using c# windows form where i have created a combobox that holds all programmes of study  and a generate button. Once this generate button is clicked a sql statement pulls all required data from the database, the where aspect of the sql statement is the selected option from the combobox, value stored as "selected".The data from the sql query is passed to a while loop that creates labels and adds data to a flow layout panel, the issue that i am having is every time i select a new programme of study from the combobox and select generate it adds the new data to the exisiting data in the flowlayoutpanel and i would like to know if it is possible to clear the flowlayout panel before generating new timetable or to override existing data .Below is the code that is carried out once the button generate is clicked.

```
private void GetData()
        {
            string selected = comboBox1.Text;
            
            
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-GCV9BH6\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=Timetabler;Integrated Security=True");
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select CourseID, CourseName, LecturerName,ProgrammeName from courses where ProgrammeName= @ProgrammeName", con);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProgrammeName", selected);
                SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();


                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    unit = new Label();
                    unit.Text = dr["CourseName"].ToString();
                    unit.Width = 120;
                    unit.Height = 95;
                    unit.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
                    unit.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

                    tutor = new Label();
                    tutor.Text = dr["LecturerName"].ToString();
                    tutor.Width = 80;
                    tutor.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(247, 167, 82);
                    tutor.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    /*
                    room = new Label();
                    room.Text = dr["name"].ToString();
                    room.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(46, 134, 222);
                    room.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    room.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;*/

                    //unit.Controls.Add(room);
                    unit.Controls.Add(tutor);
                     flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(unit);
                     unit.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;

                }
            
            dr.Close();
                con.Close();
           
        }
```

Comment: while (flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count > 0) flowLayoutPanel1.Controls[0].Dispose();

Comment: Thank you for this Hans , Im not sure if there is a way to add it to the existing code but for the time being i was able to add a separate clear button.